# Android development: OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch, 2d, motion-detection

I'm using:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
```

I'm using surfaceview.

But when I try:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    Log.d("STATE: ", "Up");
```

It is never called. What is the reason?

It is really annoying, because I want my player to move when I hold down the screen.

Comment: Are any other touch events being called? or is just for UP?

Comment: Well ive tried DOWN and it works but not UP or MOVE or CANSEL

Comment: Just curiously stupid you do know up is not the direction but the process of raising your finger?

Comment: YE i know UP should be when you release your finger right

Comment: But i never get anything in my Log.d

Comment: can we see a few more lines of code?

Comment: I just use that and else if event.getAction == ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are returning true `return true;` after you complete processing of the event (ACTION_UP in this case) and also returning `super.onTouchEvent(event)` for every other event (i.e. the default)?